# Using triggers to alter inserted/updated data to enforce a business rule

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I've just created a trigger (AFTER INSERT, UPDATE) that is designed to strip the time from a date field. I just figured that a trigger would be easier to implement than having to fix it in the application that inserts/updates the table. The latter would involve re-compiles, and kicking folks out of the app for updates.

But I'm not sure if I'm being lazy or clever, to be honest.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[StripCastDateTime] ON [dbo].[PileInventory]
    AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
    BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
       SET NOCOUNT ON;

       UPDATE PileInventory
          SET CastDate = 
                     cast(CONVERT(varchar(11), Inserted.CastDate, 101) AS datetime)
          FROM INSERTED 
          INNER JOIN [dbo].[PileInventory] AS PI
          ON     [PI].[JobNumber] = INSERTED.JobNumber
             AND [PI].[MarkNumber] = INSERTED.MarkNumber
          WHERE NOT Inserted.CastDate IS NULL 


    END

GO
```

It works perfectly, but is this a proper use of triggers?

Thanks.

Marshall

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your updated tables are big then this would hurt your DB. I would use a trigger "INSTEAD OF INSERT" to change the data and after that insert it. There is no point in doing it after it is in the DB.

Other then that .. it's a valid usage of triggers.

Read more here:
    http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175089(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: what is t'row some other such requirement come up on same table or other table?some more important business rule come up than current one.
Leave trigger to to imlpement more important business rule.if you convert it to date type then time will strip automatically.
I will select all proc who use this column then convert to date.
select * from sys.syscomments where text like '%columnname%'

Comment: That makes sense, and the table has the potential to be fairly large. But the "INSTEAD OF INSERT" would not work for updates, correct? Therefore I'd need 2 triggers?
As for other business rules, that is unlikely. My shop is just my moss and I and neither are DBA's. I'm not aure changing the data type is an option. Those kinds of changes makes my boss quite nervous and I'd rather not rock the boat, so to speak.

Comment: Yes .. you would have an instead of insert and an instead of update trigger. That would not be so bad .. just higher maintenance cost. Triggers are very neat for this kind of patching, though at some point you have to fix the application .. and remove the patching.

Answer (score 0):

I can put a business rule in the business layer. Lazy ones needs to work twice is a old said here and if you can kick people off the application in a maintenance window do it. If you do a a lot of inserts that trigger can slow down your app, also triggers are quick to grow complex and add some maintenance pain.